# PyCharm - Unable to find driver error when connecting to oracle DB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I have installed Apache Spark (spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 ) in my Mac :

```
/Users/xxxx/Software/
```

Also, I downloaded the ojdbc6.jar in the below path :

```
/Users/xxxx/Software/spark/jars
```

Below are the updates I did in my environment variables :

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/xxxx/Software/spark
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/Users/xxxx/spark_env/ojdbc6.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
alias python='python3'
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

From Terminal, I invoked pyspark and ran the below commands and it works fine.

```
conn_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:1521/USER”
 df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",conn_url).option("drive","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").option("dbtable”,”table_name”).option("user”,”xxxx”).option("password”,”xxxx”).load()
```

I am successfully able to query the DB.

Now, I am trying to do similar coding using PYCHARM more programmatically.

PyCharm Configurations :
In the Preferences->Project Structure  I have added the Content Root as below :

```
/Users/xxxx/Software/spark/jars/ojdbc6.jar
Users/xxxx/Software/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip 
/Users/xxxx/Software/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip
```

Then when I run the “main.py” (which has the code to connect and query DB) I am getting the below error :

```
Status: FailureError: An error occurred while calling o71.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding jar into project context root, it's not going to work because spark is going to look for that jar in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` folder. To do that, there are a few options:

1. In your python main script you can define it like:
   `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--jars file:///<path-to-driver>/ojdbc-<version>.jar pyspark-shell"`
2. add your driver jar in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` folder.

Comment: Hey @frosty, Thanks for the response. I added the driver jar "ojdbc6.jar" in $SPARK_HOME/jars folder already. Now as per ur comments i tried adding the below line in main,py but same issue   os.environ[
        'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /Users/xxxx/Software/spark/jars/ojdbc6.jar pyspark-shell'

Comment: `.option("drive","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` I hope you fixed that _'drive'_ to _'driver'_ . and I meant you can just do one of those options. no need to do both the things.